# is there a toSourceString() kind of function for Function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, tostring

So, I'm looking for `toSourceString()` method for Function object which will return the source code of the Function object in String format.

For example, If I have

```
(function(a, b) { 
  function useThis(c,d) { 
    return 'hello' + c + d; 
  } 
  console.log(useThis('Jenny', 'Jim')); 
}).bind(this);
```

kind of function, then I wish if I run `toSourceString()`, I will just get the inner source part of the function like:

```
function useThis(c,d) { 
   return 'hello' + c + d; 
} 
console.log(useThis('Jenny', 'Jim'));
```

Is there any default function that works across browsers? Or is there any Regex way to find some string and replace/remove the first and the end?

Comment: [Function.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString), have you checked it?

Comment: @raina77ow That returns the entire thing, not just the inside.

Comment: Of course, but it's rather trivial to extract the body, don't you think? ) My point is, have the OP investigated the docs before asking, he probably wouldn't have asked at all.

Comment: On the second thought, it seems the question is not about `toString` - but on how to extract the original function after `bind`. Would be great to have a clarification - is `bind` in the question intentional, or not.

Comment: If the question is indeed about 'bind-reversing', I don't believe it's possible. See, `Function.prototype.bind` actually creates a new function, that invokes the 'original' one with a set context (one can check `_.bind` source, for example, to study the approach). The point is, the new function is basically a compiled one - that's why its `toSource` shows just `[native code]` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myFunction.toString().replace(/^function[^{]+{/,'').slice(0,-1)
```

Gets the function, strips the beginning and end.